# Eclipse: "Method 'name' could not be resolved" for RTTI

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm migrating my ESP32 code to eclipse. After following [this manual](https://esp-idf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get-started/eclipse-setup.html#setting-up-eclipse) everything seems fine, but I get weired error on this part of code:

```
} catch(const std::exception& e) {
    std::cout << "Exception of type " << typeid(e).name() << " has been thrown: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Errors:

1. Invalid overload of 'std::endl'
2. Method 'name' could not be resolved

Adding `-frtti` flag to `CDT Cross GCC Built-in Compiler Settings` and rebuilding index didn't helped.

How can I fix this errors? Everything builds fine, but syntax analyzer shows this error.

Comment: Did you include `<typeinfo>`?

Comment: @VTT I didn't, but adding it (and rebuilding index) didn't changed anythin.